# "TO-ALL-PROPOSED-NEW-TIME" non standard ATTENDEE property parameter

Tags: caldav

Is anyone aware of an RFC describing a ATTENDEE property parameter called "TO-ALL-PROPOSED-NEW-TIME"?

macOS 10.12.4 Calendar.app has implemented propose new time using this property:

```
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=TENTATIVE;TO-ALL-PROPOSED-NEW-TIME="
 DTSTART:20170512T060000Z;STATUS:NEEDS-ACTION;":mailto:x@y.z
```

but our server is unable to parse the VCALENDAR as this property parameter is unknown.

Comment: Haven't seen that, they probably 'forgot' to prefix their propriety stuff with an `X-`. You should file a Radar.

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly a private extension so you won't find an RFC per say. Apple Calendar Server private extensions are for the most specified at https://github.com/apple/ccs-calendarserver/tree/master/doc/Extensions
but this particular one may be a pure client extension.

You may want to post your question on the Calconnect mailing list: https://www.calconnect.org/resources/discussion-lists/developers-list

Comment: Huh. I am running the same Calendar.app version and it uses the non standard "TO-ALL-PROPOSED-NEW-TIME". The property seems to come from CalendarPersistence private framework. I.e. `strings /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks//CalendarPersistence.framework/CalendarPersistence | grep PROPOSED-NEW`. But maybe it's dynamically prefixed with "X-" and our server confuses Calendar.app.

Comment: Sorry. Looked at over the wire interactions and the client is indeed sending "TO-ALL" and not "X-TO-ALL". My server is fixing the non standard parameter.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, thanks for getting back to me. I've also filed a radar with Apple but that usually takes months before an answer arrives.

Comment: Hence my suggestion to post on the calconnect mailing list. No guarantee but Apple developers are usually monitoring it.

Comment: Thanks, will do. I was under the impression the calconnect stuff was members only (calendar consortium, etc).